# php/mysql best practice for selecting items

Tags: php, mysql

I'm requesting the community's wisdom because I want to avoid bad coding practices and/or mistakes.
I'm having a php class wich is an objects manager. It does all the work with the database: inserting new data, updating it, getting it and deleting it (I've read it's called CRUD...). So it has a function that gets an element by id.

What I want to write is a function that gets a list of objects from the table.
I will then use a mysql query that goes something like

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE column1='foo'
```

And then some order by and limit/offset.

However, in my application there are different cases in which I will need different lists from this table. The WHERE clause will then be different.

Should I write different functions, one per type of list?
Or should I write one generic function to which I will send arguments that then dynamically creates the query? If so, do you have any advice on how to do this properly?

**EDIT:**
Thanks for all your answers! I should tell that I'm not using any framework (maybe wasn't the best idea...), so I didn't know about query builders. I'll investigate that (either finding a standalone uery builder or migrating to a framework or writing my own, I don't know yet). That will be useful any time I need to execute a mysql query :-)

Although I'm still confused:
Let's say I need several lists of clients (objects), for example all clients, clients over 18, clients currently online...
What approach would be best to retrieve those lists? I can either have 3 functions in my clients manager

```
allClients() {//execute a specific query and return list of objects}
allClientsOver18() {//execute specific query and return list of objects}
allClientsOnline() {//execute specific query and return list of objects}
```

or I can have one function tht builds the query based on parameters

```
listClients($some, $parameters)
{
//Build the query based on the parameters (definitely need a query builder!)
//Execute the query
//return list of objects
}
```

Which approach would be best (I guess it depends on circumstances) and mostly, why?

Thanks in advance!
Rouli

Comment: Did you use a framework or is it just plain PHP ? Some framework provide object calls "ORM" => "Object Relational Mapping", with method for querying the database like this :

$db->select()
->from("table")
->where([$field=>$condition.$value]);

You can put $field and $value in the function arguments, and choose $condition from the $field value

Comment: Nope, juste plain PHP. I had no idea about ORMs!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Thanks for all the info on query builders, I didn't even know it existed! :-) However I'm still confused as to wether I should write one specific function for each case (that function can still use the query builder to write its specific query), or write one generic function that builds dynamically the query based onf parameters. Which would be better in which case? I've added an example in my question, hope it makes it clearer!

This depends on how often you use each of these isolated queries, how complex the conditions are and how often you my need to combine the conditions with other queries. For eaxample if each the "online" and "over18" are just simple conditions then you could just use the normal `findBy` logic from my example:

```
$table = new MyTable($db);
$onlineOnly = $table->findBy(array('is_online' => true), null, null);
$over18Only = $table->findBy(array('is_over_18' => true), null, null);
$onlineOver18 = $table->findBy(array('is_over_18' => true, 'is_online' => true), null, null);
```

If the query is more complex - for example to get over 18 clients you have to do:

```
select client.*, (YEAR(CURDATE()) - YEAR(client.birthdate)) as age 
FROM client
WHERE age >= 18
```

Then its probably better to make this into a separate method or create methods to work on `Query` objects directly to add complex conditions for example - especially if you will need this condition in a few different queries in the app:

```
$table = new MyTable($db);

// creates a basic query defaulted to SELECT * FROM table_name
$query = $table->createQuery();

// adds the complex condition for over 18 resulting in
// SELECT table_name.*, (YEAR(CURDATE()) - YEAR(table_name.birthdate)) as age WHERE age >= 18
$over18 = $table->applyOver18Query($query)->execute();
```

This way you can apply your over 18 condition easily to any query with out manually manipulating the builder ensure that your over 18 condition is consistent. But for simplicity you could also have a convenience method like the following:

```
public function findOver18By(array $criteria, $limit = null, $offest = null) {

    $query = $this->findBy($criteria, $limit, $offset);
    $this->applyOver18Query($query);
    return $query->execute();
}
```

---

Normally you would use some kind of query builder at the lower level like:

```
$query = $db->createQuery()
  ->select($fields)
  ->from($tableName)
  ->where($fieldName, $value);

$results = $query->execute();
```

Then you might have a class that makes use of this like:

```
class MyTable
{
   protected $tableName = 'my_table';

   protected $db;

   public function __construct($db) {
      $this->db = $db;
   }

   public function findBy(array $criteria, $limit = null, $offset = null) {
        $query = $this->db->createQuery();
        $query->select('*')->from($this->tableName);

        foreach ($criteria as $col => $value) {
            // andWhere would determine internally whether or not
            // this is the initial WHERE clause or an AND clause
            // something similar would happen with an orWhere method
            $query->andWhere($col, $value);
        }

        if (null !== $limit) {
           $query->limit($limit);
        }

        if (null !== $offset) {
           $query->offset($offset);
        }

        return $query->execute();
   }
}
```

Usage would look like:

```
$table = new MyTable($db);
$result = $table->findBy(array('column1' => 'foo'), null, null);
```

This is a lot to implement on your own. Most people use an ORM or a DBAL to provide these features and those are often included with a framework like [Eloquent with Laravel](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent), or [Doctrine with Symfony](http://www.doctrine-project.org/).

Comment: Thanks for all the info on query builders, I didn't even know it existed! :-)
However I'm still confused as to wether I should write one specific function for each case (that function can still use the query builder to write its specific query), or write one generic function that builds dynamically the query based onf parameters. 
Which would be better in which case?
I've added an example in my question, hope it makes it clearer!

Comment: @Rouli Updated with some more suggestions... Also [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/) is a component you can integrate into an application regardless of the framework its using. You can use the [DBAL](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/dbal.html) which is just db abstraction (including a query builder like i have described) or you can use the full [ORM](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm.html) which actually maps PHP Objects to the database.

Answer (score 0):

I guess at start you should need some main data like

```
$main = [
    'from'  = '`from_table`',
]
```

Then you should add selects if had

```
$selects = ['fields1','field2'];

$where = ['some condition', 'other condition'];
```

Then you could

```
$query = "SELECT ".implode(',', $selects ." FROM ".$main['from']."
WHERE ".implode('AND ', $where .";";
```

That's some approaches for simple one table query.
If you need Joins, then `$selects` better would be make with aliasos, so no field will be lost if they are not different, like

```
select temp.id as temp_id , temp2.id temp2_id from temp
left join temp2 on temp2.temp_id = temp.id
```

Feel free to ask some questions, maybe i haven't told , but you should also check bound parameters with some functions to avoid sql injections

Comment: Then then conditions in $where will include my table's column names ? like `id IN (some, ids, list)` ?
Then if for example I change my table's column names, I will need to change the parameters in $where in all the places where I use the function... As opposed to having different functions in a file, then it's easier to change the column names since it's all in the same file, at the same place... ?

Also, what would be the best way to escape the parameters? Should I use addslashes() when I construct the $where array?

Answer (score -1):

I suggest using a **CLASS** for your database which holds all your database accessing functions as it makes your code cleaner making it more easier to look through for errors or modifications.

```
class Database
{
public function connect()   {   }
public function disconnect()    {   }
public function select()        {   }
public function insert()        {   }
public function delete()        {   }
public function update()    {   }
}
```

**sample connect function** for connecting to a selected database.

```
private db_host = ‘’; 
private db_user = ‘’; 
private db_pass = ‘’; 
private db_name = ‘’; 

public function connect()
    {
    if(!$this->con)
    {
        $myconn = mysqli_connect($this->db_host,$this->db_user,$this->db_pass);
        if($myconn)
        {
            $seldb = mysqli_select_db($this->db_name,$myconn);
            if($seldb)
            {
                $this->con = true; 
                return true; 
            } else
            {
                return false; 
            }
        } else
        {
            return false; 
        }
    } else
    {
        return true; 
    }
}
```

with this approach will make creating CRUD functions easier. Heres a sample **insert** function.

```
public function insert($table,$values,$rows = null)
{
    if($this->tableExists($table))
    {
        $insert = 'INSERT INTO '.$table;
        if($rows != null)
        {
            $insert .= ' ('.$rows.')'; 
        }

        for($i = 0; $i < count($values); $i++)
        {
            if(is_string($values[$i]))
                $values[$i] = '"'.$values[$i].'"';
        }
        $values = implode(',',$values);
        $insert .= ' VALUES ('.$values.')';
        $ins = @mysql_query($insert);            
        if($ins)
        {
            return true; 
        }
        else
        {
            return false; 
        }
    }
}
```

heres a quick view on using this.

```
;<?php;
$db->insert('myDataBase',array(3,"Name 4","this@wasinsert.ed")); //this takes 3 paramteres
$result = $db->getResult(); //Assuming you already have getResult() function.
print_r($result);
?>
```

**EDIT**

there are more purist approach to handling database operations. I highly suggest it because handling information is very delicate and should be fronted with many **safety measures** But it requires deeper php knowledge. Try [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php) for php and [this article](http://mattbango.com/notebook/code/prepared-statements-in-php-and-mysqli/) by **matt bango** on **prepared statements** and its **significance**.

Comment: Downvote for including examples in with `mysql_*` and for using the `@` error suppression. Either let the errors do their thing or throw an exception that can be caught. You also didn't quote your values for the insert.

Comment: @prodigitalson thanks! changed the mysql to mysqli. sorry bout that.